# How can I correctly set all elements of an array to a negative value?

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have a program where it asks the user to for a certain amount and elements and creates the array, and then after initializing all elements to zero, it now sets all elements to negative -1. I have a segmentation fault and I think it's due to my code for setting the elements to -1. What would be a better way for set all elements to negative one? And if possible, explain why.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {  

    cout << endl << "A dynamic array creation program" << endl;

    size_t length = 0;  
    int * intArray = nullptr;  

    cout << endl << "Input number of elements: ";  
    cin >> length;  

    cout << endl << "Allocating memory to create the dynamic array" << endl;  
    intArray = new int [length];  

    cout << endl << "Initializing all elements to 0" << endl;  
    for (size_t i=0; i<length; ++i)    
        intArray[i] = 0;  

    cout << endl << "Deallocating the dynamic array" << endl;  
    delete [] intArray;  
    intArray = nullptr; 

    cout << endl << "Setting all elements to negative values" << endl;  
    for (size_t i=0; i<length; ++i)    
        intArray[i] = -1;  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you *Setting all elements to negative values* after you *Deallocating the dynamic array*? To put it another way, Why are you trying to fill and array you have already deleted?

Comment: Do you know what it means to deallocate the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> after initializing all elements to zero, it now sets all elements to negative -1.

It does something else after setting all elements to zero. It deletes the array. The elements no longer exist at the point where you assign -1.

> What would be a better way for set all elements to negative one?

Doing it before the array is deleted.

> And if possible, explain why.

Because if you attempt to access objects outside of their lifetime, the behaviour of the program will be undefined.